# Google Developer Console - Paid Apps (for Non-US Resident)

Tags: android, android-pay, merchant-account

This question has already been asked a lot of times but no complete/detailed answer has been provided so far.

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question. I need to configure the Google Developer Console (and Google Wallet as well) in order to sell apps in Play Store. As you probably know Google has a list and not all countries are easily allowed to sell applications. However, there is one workaround using Payoneer and Google Wallet in order to get money from the apps sold. Basically you need to obtain an account in Payoneer and apply for "US Payment Services", doing this you will get a banck account in the US, after that you will need to create a Google Wallet Merchant Account and here is the problem:If your country is not listed in Google as an allowed location you will need to change the configuration in Google Wallet to an US address (you can get one in usbox.com for instance) and after that you will be able to create the Merchant account. The problem is that sells in Play Stores fail even if these steps were completed. I think that the problem is that I cannot verify my identity because I don't have an SSN or ITIN number.

Does anyone have more experience about this or know the required steps and configuration for Non-US Residents?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer because if you are not a US resident, it still depends on your country.  Depending on your country, you may get paid through wire transfer:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2700656?hl=en

This applies to many but not all non US residents.

The general process is described here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/173779?hl=en